# Bluebird coroutine() is difficult to debug in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, bluebird, coroutine

I'm using bluebird co-routines in my Node.js application.

When I'm setting breakpoints in the code, it is very hard to debug the code 
since the **debugger doesn't stop** (to be more accurate stops for 1 second) 
at the breakpoint and immediately throws an error with a huge stack trace which really doesn't help.

I'm using mac OSX 10.11.6

Node v6.0.0

webstorm 2016.2.2

Did someone encountered the same problem?

The error says:

```
Process finished with exit code 132 SIGILL
```

Example for the thrown exception when debugging:

```
// stack-allocated locals
  var arguments = 0x298a35180cd9 <an Arguments with map 0xd8d3750a509>#52#
  var target = 0x31e5ff8c7411 <JS Function next (SharedFunctionInfo 0x31e5ff867f09)>#53#
  // expression stack (top to bottom)
  [05] : 0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>
  [04] : 0x298a3517ee71 <JS Generator>#8#
  [03] : 0x31e5ff8ba189 <JS Function apply (SharedFunctionInfo 0x31e5ff881af1)>#54#
  [02] : 0x22420b724f59 <FixedArray[48]>#55#
--------- s o u r c e   c o d e ---------
function tryCatcher() {\x0a    try {\x0a        var target = tryCatchTarget;\x0a        tryCatchTarget = null;\x0a        return target.apply(this, arguments);\x0a    } catch (e) {\x0a        errorObj.e = e;\x0a        return errorObj;\x0a    }\x0a}
-----------------------------------------
}
[16]: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0 {
  // actual arguments
  [00] : 0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>  // not passed to callee
}
[17]: _promiseFulfilled [/Users/XXXXXXXXX/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:97] [pc=0x8679b27641] (this=0x298a3517ef21 <a PromiseSpawn with map 0x115102551369>#9#,value=0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>) {
  // stack-allocated locals
  var result = 0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>
  // expression stack (top to bottom)
  [03] : 0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>
  [02] : 0x298a3517ee71 <JS Generator>#8#
  [01] : 0x31e5ff8ba219 <JS Function call (SharedFunctionInfo 0x31e5ff881cd1)>#56#
--------- s o u r c e   c o d e ---------
function (value) {\x0a    this._yieldedPromise = null;\x0a    this._promise._pushContext();\x0a    var result = tryCatch(this._generator.next).call(this._generator, value);\x0a    this._promise._popContext();\x0a    this._continue(result);\x0a}
-----------------------------------------
}
[18]: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/Users/xxxxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:201] [pc=0x8679b253e0] (this=0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>) {
  // stack-allocated locals
  var arguments = 0x298a3517edb1 <an Arguments with map 0xd8d3750a509>#57#
  var generator = 0x298a3517ee71 <JS Generator>#8#
  var spawn = 0x298a3517ef21 <a PromiseSpawn with map 0x115102551369>#9#
  var ret = 0x298a3517f041 <a Promise with map 0x21ef8a9d919>#58#
  // expression stack (top to bottom)
  [06] : 0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>
  [05] : 0x298a3517ef21 <a PromiseSpawn with map 0x115102551369>#9#
  [04] : 0x3efd362e231 <JS Function PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (SharedFunctionInfo 0x3efd362d579)>#59#
--------- s o u r c e   c o d e ---------
function () {\x0a        var generator = generatorFunction.apply(this, arguments);\x0a        var spawn = new PromiseSpawn$(undefined, undefined, yieldHandler,\x0a                                      stack);\x0a        var ret = spawn.promise();\x0a        spawn._generator = generator;\x0a        spawn._promiseFulfilled(unde...
-----------------------------------------
}
[19]: getData [/Users/xxxxx.js:113] [pc=0x86797f7f39] (this=0x298a3500c8d1 <an Object with map 0x1151025fece9>#10#,segmentId=0x298a350cbe39 <String[1]: 1>) {
  // heap-allocated locals
  var segmentId = 0x298a350cbe39 <String[1]: 1>
  // expression stack (top to bottom)
  [02] : 0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>
  [01] : 0x298a3517ed59 <JS Function (SharedFunctionInfo 0x2b5de62a3bb9)>#60#
  [00] : 0x2cd86ebd7861 <JS Function getData (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1e90f7205ba1)>#61#
--------- s o u r c e   c o d e ---------
function getData(segmentId) {\x0a    chartsService.init();\x0a\x0a    return co(function * hdlr() {\x0a      const modelData = {};\x0a      console.log('getData segmentId:' + segmentId.toString());\x0a      const getChartResult = yield chartsService.getBySegmentId(segmentId);\x0a      //console.log('after getData segmentId:' + segmentI...
-----------------------------------------
}
[20]: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1 {
  // actual arguments
  [00] : 0x298a350cbe39 <String[1]: 1>
  [01] : 0x298a350ce801 <an Object with map 0x115102551999>#62#  // not passed to callee
}
[21]: hdlr(aka hdlr) [/xxxxcontroller.js:45] [pc=0x8679b25b85] (this=0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>) {
  // heap-allocated locals
  var this = 0x31e5ff804189 <undefined>
  var .generator_object = 0x298a350ce091 <JS Generator>#11#
  var variant = 0x31e5ff886891 <String[7]: default>
  var service = 0x298a3500c8d1 <an Object with map 0x1151025fece9>#10#
  var opts = 0x298a350ce801 <an Object with map 0x115102551999>#62#
  var getResult = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  var templateData = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  var modelData = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  var assetPaths = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  var processedHtml = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  var assetsResult = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  var css = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  var js = 0x31e5ff8041e9 <the hole>
  // expression stack (top to bottom)
  [04] : 0x298a350ce801 <an Object with map 0x115102551999>#62#
  [03] : 0x298a350cbe39 <String[1]: 1>
  [02] : 0x298a3500c8d1 <an Object with map 0x1151025fece9>#10#
  [01] : 0x2cd86ebd7861 <JS Function getData (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1e90f7205ba1)>#61#
  [00] : 0x298a350cdfd9 <FixedArray[18]>#63#
--------- s o u r c e   c o d e ---------
function hdlr()
```

Comment: that sounds more like a JIT bug where it generated invalid machine instructions... what node version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Node v6.0.0